# Get Child name (relation) out of Contacts App

Tags: contacts, google-apps-script

I'm extracting contacts with ContactsApp and can get email and namnes, but can not find out how to get "Child"-namne out of the contacts.
I tried with "CustomField". I can create a custom field and read it, but there is no "Child"-field.

How do I get "Child"-namne out of the contacts?

Test code for Google Apps script

```
function doGet(e) {


  var GroupObject = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('TestGrupp');
  var ContactsTestGrupp = GroupObject.getContacts();
  var nrContacts = ContactsTestGrupp.length;

  var objectContact;
  var emailString;
  var GivenNameString;
  var FamilyNameString;
   for(var i = 0; i < nrContacts; i++) {
    objectContact = ContactsTestGrupp[i].getEmails();
    emailString = objectContact[0].getAddress();
    Logger.log(emailString);
    GivenNameString = ContactsTestGrupp[i].getGivenName();
    FamilyNameString = ContactsTestGrupp[i].getFamilyName();
      Logger.log(GivenNameString + ' ' + FamilyNameString);

    } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Contacts has a field for child name, at least not that I can find.